# How to flatten a nested JSON from the NASA Weather Insight API in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, api, weather-api

Hello I am trying to display the mars weather from the [Mars Insight API](https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/weather/). The issue that is occurring is that the data is returning in JSON format and has three levels [API Documentation](https://api.nasa.gov/assets/insight/InSight%20Weather%20API%20Documentation.pdf). I can pull the primary key no problem with 3-4 different methods but when I try to get a secondary or tertiary key that is when it falls apart.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

API_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=nTal99zKlhGbl0N8F0V9iUofifMdcwyOHw64CrVm&feedtype=json&ver=1.0"
API_data = requests.get(API_url).json()

# define weather data attributes

#AT = {'AT':API_data['sol_keys'[1,2,3]]}
#PRE = {'PRE':API_data['sol_keys']}
#HWS = {'HWS':API_data['sol_keys']}
#Season= {'Season':API_data['sol_keys']}
#WD = {'WD':API_data['sol_keys']}
#most_common = {'most_common':API_data['sol_keys']}

context = {'sol_keys': API_data["sol_keys"]}

data =json_normalize(API_data, 'sol_keys', '301','AT')

print (data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use recursion to flatten the nested `dicts`

- [Thinking Recursively in Python](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)
- [Flattening JSON objects in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)
- [flatten](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)
- The `flatten_json` function, will be used to flatten `data`

```py
def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=['']) -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests

API_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/insight_weather/?api_key=nTal99zKlhGbl0N8F0V9iUofifMdcwyOHw64CrVm&feedtype=json&ver=1.0"
API_data = requests.get(API_url).json()

# create a list of dicts: these are the values of each sol_key
data = [API_data[x] for x in API_data['sol_keys']]

# if you also want the sol_key to be included in the data
# it needs to be added back in as a key: value pair
for i, value in enumerate(data, 301):
    value.update({'sol_key': i})

# expand all the values
df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data])
```

#### Output

```py
 sol_key   AT_av   AT_ct    AT_mn   AT_mx             First_UTC  HWS_av  HWS_ct  HWS_mn  HWS_mx              Last_UTC   PRE_av  PRE_ct    PRE_mn    PRE_mx  Season  WD_1_compass_degrees WD_1_compass_point  WD_1_compass_right  WD_1_compass_up  WD_1_ct  WD_10_compass_degrees WD_10_compass_point  WD_10_compass_right  WD_10_compass_up  WD_10_ct  WD_11_compass_degrees WD_11_compass_point  WD_11_compass_right  WD_11_compass_up  WD_11_ct  WD_12_compass_degrees WD_12_compass_point  WD_12_compass_right  WD_12_compass_up  WD_12_ct  WD_13_compass_degrees WD_13_compass_point  WD_13_compass_right  WD_13_compass_up  WD_13_ct  WD_2_compass_degrees WD_2_compass_point  WD_2_compass_right  WD_2_compass_up  WD_2_ct  WD_3_compass_degrees WD_3_compass_point  WD_3_compass_right  WD_3_compass_up  WD_3_ct  WD_5_compass_degrees WD_5_compass_point  WD_5_compass_right  WD_5_compass_up  WD_5_ct  WD_6_compass_degrees WD_6_compass_point  WD_6_compass_right  WD_6_compass_up  WD_6_ct  WD_7_compass_degrees WD_7_compass_point  WD_7_compass_right  WD_7_compass_up  WD_7_ct  WD_8_compass_degrees WD_8_compass_point  WD_8_compass_right  WD_8_compass_up  WD_8_ct  WD_9_compass_degrees WD_9_compass_point  WD_9_compass_right  WD_9_compass_up  WD_9_ct  WD_most_common_compass_degrees WD_most_common_compass_point  WD_most_common_compass_right  WD_most_common_compass_up  WD_most_common_ct  WD_14_compass_degrees WD_14_compass_point  WD_14_compass_right  WD_14_compass_up  WD_14_ct  WD_0_compass_degrees WD_0_compass_point  WD_0_compass_right  WD_0_compass_up  WD_0_ct
     301 -69.684  342720 -103.886 -26.371  2019-10-01T11:46:39Z   4.630  158626   0.129  17.919  2019-10-02T12:26:13Z  727.941  153492  711.7187  743.1005  spring                  22.5                NNE            0.382683          0.92388      4.0                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     26723                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683     15528                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0      3136                  292.5                 WNW             -0.92388          0.382683       2.0                  45.0                 NE            0.707107         0.707107      6.0                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683      688                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683     3387                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    40327                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    31608                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0     8520                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388    28697                           135.0                           SE                      0.707107                  -0.707107              40327                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN
     302 -68.977  339696 -102.032 -25.338  2019-10-02T12:26:14Z   4.781  154660   0.208  20.153  2019-10-03T13:05:49Z  727.076  168657  710.8055  741.8326  spring                  22.5                NNE            0.382683          0.92388      1.0                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     32482                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683      1508                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0        27                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                  45.0                 NE            0.707107         0.707107     16.0                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683     1757                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683     2178                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    25516                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    36367                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0    26800                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388    28008                           157.5                          SSE                      0.382683                  -0.923880              36367                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN
     303 -67.094  257650 -103.946 -26.523  2019-10-03T13:05:50Z   4.911  113599   0.131  19.147  2019-10-04T13:45:24Z  724.189  110794  711.2929  741.7360  spring                  22.5                NNE            0.382683          0.92388      6.0                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     16663                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683      5999                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0      8920                  292.5                 WNW             -0.92388          0.382683      23.0                  45.0                 NE            0.707107         0.707107     12.0                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683      507                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683     1041                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    21889                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    29209                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0     9400                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388    19919                           157.5                          SSE                      0.382683                  -0.923880              29209                  315.0                  NW            -0.707107          0.707107      11.0                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN
     304 -68.042  308602 -104.325 -25.869  2019-10-04T13:45:25Z   4.959  140757   0.132  18.224  2019-10-05T14:25:00Z  724.808  152271  707.9475  741.3935  spring                  22.5                NNE            0.382683          0.92388      6.0                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     18480                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683      9226                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0     16455                  292.5                 WNW             -0.92388          0.382683      12.0                  45.0                 NE            0.707107         0.707107      2.0                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683     1006                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683     1622                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    27717                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    36692                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0    13210                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388    16329                           157.5                          SSE                      0.382683                  -0.923880              36692                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN
     305 -71.205  229742 -104.059 -27.287  2019-10-05T14:25:01Z   4.874  103937   0.128  22.241  2019-10-06T15:04:35Z  722.192  157557  708.6817  738.4189  spring                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     15124                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683      4252                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0      3027                  292.5                 WNW             -0.92388          0.382683      11.0                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683       71                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683      712                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    15842                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    34545                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0    13445                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388    16908                           157.5                          SSE                      0.382683                  -0.923880              34545                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN
     306 -72.664  215500 -102.655 -25.681  2019-10-06T15:04:36Z   4.437  101771   0.131  17.113  2019-10-07T15:44:09Z  720.791  125256  706.1014  740.7565  spring                  22.5                NNE            0.382683          0.92388      1.0                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     16025                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683      2200                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0      6820                  292.5                 WNW             -0.92388          0.382683      63.0                  45.0                 NE            0.707107         0.707107      3.0                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683      265                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683      747                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    15702                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    20971                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0    18328                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388    20646                           157.5                          SSE                      0.382683                  -0.923880              20971                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                   NaN                NaN                 NaN              NaN      NaN
     307 -71.995  175881 -102.027 -26.828  2019-10-07T15:44:10Z   4.948   82571   0.206  18.374  2019-10-08T10:12:49Z  724.898   87860  704.6372  739.6598  spring                  22.5                NNE            0.382683          0.92388      7.0                  225.0                  SW            -0.707107         -0.707107     13459                  247.5                 WSW             -0.92388         -0.382683      9642                  270.0                   W                 -1.0              -0.0      6382                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                  45.0                 NE            0.707107         0.707107      3.0                  67.5                ENE             0.92388         0.382683      171                 112.5                ESE             0.92388        -0.382683      655                 135.0                 SE            0.707107        -0.707107    12847                 157.5                SSE            0.382683         -0.92388    19655                 180.0                  S                 0.0             -1.0    12628                 202.5                SSW           -0.382683         -0.92388     7121                           157.5                          SSE                      0.382683                  -0.923880              19655                    NaN                 NaN                  NaN               NaN       NaN                   0.0                  N                 0.0              1.0      1.0
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!